# SSL error on a freshly installed QGIS 2.14.1

Tags: installation, qgis-2.14

I would like to ask for a help on how to fix the SSL error I'm having on a fresh installed QGIS 2.14.1 version. It seems to me it's the reason why vector, raster, and some other tools won't work when I use it. It crashes my QGIS every time. Can somebody point out how can I possibly fix the problem?

Please see attached images for reference.

[image: SSL error]

[image: Sample error when using vector clipping tool]

Comment: It appears from the error that you are using a self signed certificate. What happens if you tick the box `Save SSL server exception`

Comment: I have similar problem. "SSL error occured during access of URL" but our URL referred to is *https://qgis.org/version.txt* Is it possible to not get the error message in the first place? Regards:
Fredric

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I copy / paste [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266705/custom-certificate-configuration-error-message/267625#267625) here since this question has more views.

I had a similar issue during QGis 2.18.10 startup.

> SSL Certificate Errors occured accessing URL :
>
> https://ubuntu.qgis.org/version.txt
>
> Unable To Get Local Issuer Certificate: The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found

I fixed it by going to https://ubuntu.qgis.org/version.txt with IE.

Alternatively, using Powershell :

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://ubuntu.qgis.org/version.txt
```

or (for Powershell < 3.0)

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://ubuntu.qgis.org/version.txt")
```

My guess is that any of these actions add the qgis certificate (or maybe let's encrypt CA) to the certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

Add the system Environment path to give the permission for SSL Request in QGIS -

System Environment setup -:

Variable Name- : GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL
Variable Value- : YES

Variable Name- : GDAL_HTTP_USERAGENT
Variable Value- : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36