# Custom Certificate Configuration error message

Tags: qgis

When I run QGIS v. 2.18.15 on my PC I get this error message when the program first starts up:

- Unable To Get Local Issuer Certificate: The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found

Is there any way I can fix this issue, because currently I am not able to install any new plugins. I've tried googling the error message but I am not able to find any helpful solutions! [image: Picture showing error message]

Comment: click Ignore then load QGIS up and go to the plugins, it seems to work that way.

Comment: You're correct, seems to have worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: @Mapperz Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

click  `Ignore`
on the Custom Certificate Configuration error message, then load QGIS up and go to the plugins, it seems to work that way.

Have tested this on a windows 10 (64 bit version of QGIS).

not tested on the development version 2.99 (to be 3.0).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue during QGis 2.18.10 startup.

> SSL Certificate Errors occured accessing URL :
>
> https://ubuntu.qgis.org/version.txt
>
> Unable To Get Local Issuer Certificate: The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found

I fixed it by going to https://ubuntu.qgis.org/version.txt with IE.

Alternatively, using Powershell :

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://ubuntu.qgis.org/version.txt
```

or (for Powershell < 3.0)

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://ubuntu.qgis.org/version.txt")
```

My guess is that any of these actions add the qgis certificate (or maybe let's encrypt CA) to the certificate store.

Hope that helps.