# How to ignore SSL Certificate in QGIS

Tags: ssl

I've already clicked ok so all servers that don't have SSL can't be loaded in QGIS. Where to change these settings? How to display this menu?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Certificate Configuration error message](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266705/custom-certificate-configuration-error-message)

Comment: @pkExec No, I have to ignore the ssl error because yesterday I clicked the wrong one so it only shows the message "Connection Failed : Network Error" when connecting to ArcGIS Rest.

Comment: Because yesterday i click save SSL server exception so now the server can't acces and make some trouble like "SSL handsake failed" so i need to ignore the SSL.

Comment: Are you on QGIS 2.x?!

Answer (score 3):

You are not mentioning version of QGIS you are using. Also the question in your question body is different than what you're mentioning in the comments.

Anyway, if your question is "how to display the Custom Certificate Configuration window", then for QGIS 3.16 the answer is:

Settings -> Options -> Authentication tab -> "Manage certificates" button -> Servers tab -> Click on the "plus" icon.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for making you confusing and thanks for the information.