# Plugin install failed in QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, plugins

I've been using QGIS 2.6 and whenever I try to install some plugin through plugin manager, it returns an error `"Plugin installation failed:SSL handshake failed"`.
I have always had to manually install plugins since then.

Can anyone suggest me solution to this ?

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221061/ssl-error-on-a-freshly-installed-qgis-2-14-1

Comment: @AndreJ idk, may be not ! looks quite different issue to me!

Comment: Try to visit the plugin homepage and download it manually. In most cases your PC does not like the certificate and needs an exception to be stored. Or check if your SSL libs are up to date.